# Remove Client via Rest API

Tags: keycloak

I am using the:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

I would like in a programmatic way to remove the Client.

Unfortunately as I see `ClientsResource` from `keycloak.realm("my-realm").clients()` has only create option:

```
 @POST
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 Response create(ClientRepresentation clientRepresentation);
```

Is there any way to remove the client using REST API? Or lack of this option is intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on [docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html#_clients_resource) there is such API: `DELETE /{realm}/clients/{id}`.

```java
keycloak.realm("realm").clients().get("id").remove();
```

Comment: This uses the admin API, isn't there an API for the current user?